# How long it would take for PCT to publish the application if I request early publication?

Tags: pct, early-publication

To quote [this page](https://www.wipo.int/pct/en/newslett/practical_advice/pa_102016.html)

> The IB will do its best to publish the international application as
>   soon as possible after receipt of the request for early publication,
>   provided that any necessary fees have been paid.  Note, however, that
>   publication will not be immediate, as the IB will, for operational
>   reasons, need some time to prepare your application for publication. 
>   For example, if the abstract has not yet been translated, the PCT
>   Translation Division would need time to do this.  The IB will
>   acknowledge receipt of your request for early publication, and will
>   notify you of the new scheduled publication date.

Can anyone provide me an estimate for the "need some time" part?

Also how much does it cost to request early publication in PCT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got a detailed reply from PCT via email. Quite honestly, I didn't expect such a detailed mail from PCT.

I hope someone will find this info useful.

---

In order to submit an online request to the IB to publish an international application before the expiration of 18 months from the priority date, select the Action ‘Request for early publication.’

Open the application in your Workbench after signing in to ePCT with strong authentication methods.  Go to the ACTIONS section and click the small triangle to open the section and select the action.

[image]

[image]

The system will warn you if technical preparations for international publication are too close to completion, or indeed are already complete, and it is therefore no longer possible to request earlier publication.

[image]

[image]

Note that, if the IB has not yet received the ISR or the Declaration under Article 17.2(a), information is displayed as to the payment of the special publication fee of 200 Swiss francs. Note that it is not yet possible to pay this special publication fee online in ePCT and a separate invoice will be issued by the IB.

[image]

Before submitting it is compulsory to sign the Action by selecting a signature option. You can either submit immediately or save a draft of the Action to be submitted later. After submitting, the rendered documents are displayed in the Documents section making up the Record as held by the IB.

[image]

In general, in case of a request for early publication, the application is published between, 6 and 10 weeks after the request and payment made

Comment: The PCT help desk is very helpful, both at the IB and at the USPTO